# Problems with {% extends 'base.html' %} using cookiecutter

Tags: python, django, jinja2, cookiecutter

I am trying to create a project template using cookiecutter, my problem is that I am receiving the next error:

```
 File "./{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}/templates/{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}/home.html", line 1, in top-level template code
  File "/Users/osvaldo/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 187, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: base.html
```

The file `home.html` contains the next piece of code:

```
{% raw %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% endraw %}
```

Can anyone tell me what would be the correct way to escape the `extends` tag?

Comment: You are using Jinja2 with Django? How is it integrated?

Comment: `File  "./{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}/templates/{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}/home.html", line 1, in top-level template code`:
Do you really have a directory on your computer called `{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}`? My guess is you just need to update your template files directory setting to contain the actual project name.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to escape the `extends` tag:

```
{{ "{%" }} extends {{ "%}" }}
```

As per OP @Osvaldo Cordova A's edit on the question.